# Create and save text file

Tags: c#

I am trying to create and save text file in c#. When I write code its working with `localhost` very smooth but when I upload this code on ftp then it stops working.

This code is working on local host very well but not on ftp.

```
StreamWriter _testData;
_testData = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\Downloads\sample.txt", true);
_testData.WriteLine(text); // Write the file.
_testData.Close(); // Close the instance of StreamWriter.
_testData.Dispose(); // Dispose from memory.
```

Comment: What error do you get? Maybe there's no such folder `C:\Users\Public\Downloads` on your remote server? Or maybe the user you are running your application under doesn't have permissions to write to this folder? Also you don't need to `Close` and `Dispose`. Simply wrapping the `StreamWriter` in a `using` statement will be enough.

Comment: By the way, you could do all of that with two lines of code if you use `using`:  `using (StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\Downloads\sample.txt", true)) { _testData.WriteLine(text); }`

Comment: Actually he can do all this in a single line of code: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\Downloads\sample.txt", text);` :-)

Comment: you cant write to an FTP site using the StreamWriter. What are you trying to do? Do you also have permission to write to the folder in question? (Even though it is Public - still, worth checking)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, he is not writing to an FTP using a StreamWriter. He is using FTP to upload his web application to a remote server and there his application stops working because on this remote server there's no such folder `C:\Users\Public\Downloads` in which he is trying to write.

Comment: i m not getting any error on server. And also the file is not created in such directory. @DarinDimitrov

Comment: Can you tell me the right approch for saving the text file on my machine. @Ahmedilyas

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application?

Comment: You will have to use Server.MapPath to get access of your domain directory, generally you dont have access to C:\Users\Public\Downloads\ folder. Make sure the folder which you want to use have 777 permission.

Comment: yes in asp.net mvc application. @johnnycardy